# PROLOG - Get a list of all the rules an entity verifies

Tags: prolog, predicate, linguistics

I'm formalizing linguistic data into predicates and entities and doing some reasoning in prolog. Imagine I begin with:

```
breathe(X) :- snore(X).
sleep(X) :- snore(X).
rest(X) :- sleep(X).
live(X) :- breathe(X); eat(X); sleep(X).

snore(john).
sleep(lucy).
```

My data can get big enough and I would like to get a list of entities and predicates in order to iterate them and check how many predicates an entity verifies, the output can be lists like:

```
[john, [snore, breathe, sleep, rest, live]]
[lucy, [sleep, rest]]
```

or predicates

```
participant(john, [snore, breathe, sleep, rest, live]).
participant(lucy, [sleep, rest]).
```

Thanks for your help, I have no clue at this moment.

Comment: You want for forward-chain in backward-chaining Prolog. Works (because Prolog is a general programming language), but remains awkward. Maybe using CHR (if your Prolog has an extension for that) would be more appropriate.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Is there a better alternative language to what I want than prolog, for instance in python?

Comment: Well, if you know Prolog, you should stay with Prolog as it is high-level and useful enough. Going back to "imperative programming" à la Python means learning about (or even implementing) a library that provides needed functionality, which is doesn't save you. CapelliC's idea is correct. See also [Forward chaining in YAP Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466682/forward-chaining-in-yap-prolog) and I had some excessive time/fun in writing [Forward and Backward Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376526/forward-and-backward-chaining).

Comment: Alternatively, you could invest in learning about high-level tools like [Grakn](https://grakn.ai/), if you really want to go that far and the cost/benefit ratio is favorable. Another possibility is that you could write your own mini-language and corresponding interpreter in Prolog but that also demands climbing the knowledge cliff.

Answer (score 3):

Representing live knowledge about an abstract world can get messy. There are a lot of different possibilities, and a lot of variance depending of which Prolog system you're using.

Here is an example of your code running in SWI-Prolog, but the same idea should work (more or less) unchanged on any Prolog out there that provides [call/N](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2) and [setof](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3)/3 builtins.

```
:- module(list_entities_that_verify_a_pred,
          [participant/2]).

:- redefine_system_predicate(sleep/1).
:- discontiguous breathe/1,sleep/1,rest/1,live/1,snore/1.

breathe(X) :- snore(X).
sleep(X) :- snore(X).
rest(X) :- sleep(X).
live(X) :- breathe(X); /* eat(X);*/ sleep(X).

snore(john).
sleep(lucy).

to_verify(breathe).
to_verify(sleep).
to_verify(rest).
to_verify(live).
to_verify(snore).

participant(Person,Verified) :-
    setof(Pred,(to_verify(Pred),call(Pred,Person)),Verified).
```

First, note I have commented the call to eat/1, to avoid a missing definition exception, so we can try to call the partecipant/2 predicate:

```
?- participant(P,L).
P = john,
L = [breathe, live, rest, sleep, snore] ;
P = lucy,
L = [live, rest, sleep].
```

From an architecture viewpoint, the main point to note it's the introduction of to_verify/1, to ease the workflow.

Comment: Is there a way to expose the eat predicate and the like? It looks like I'm going to have a lot of unmatched predicate networks like owl and proton because I'm going to use few facts and a lot of semantic relations from Wordnet. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Sorry, it's a difficult question, I don't have any 'silver bullet' ready. Which wordnet interface are you using ? That one provided by SWI-Prolog pack ?

Comment: I've converted a part of wordnet to implications, meaning postulates with python. Maybe prolog it's not the adequate tool to get a list of predicates.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using forward chaining using [Constraint Handling Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_Handling_Rules), an underappreciated paradigm of computation.

This is done using SWI-Prolog's [CHR library](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chr). The rule engine is implemented "on top of Prolog" and adding a rule to the "constraint store" looks like calling a Prolog goal. The "constraint store" holding the current state of computation disappears once the goal completes.

Note that I'm currently not 100% certain of CHR semantics (it seems my brain is hardwired to read Prolog now) but this code seems to work.

In file `sleep.pl`:

```
:- module(forward,[
                  snore/1,
                  sleep/1,
                  collect/2,
                  pull/2
                  ]).

:- use_module(library(chr)).

:- chr_constraint snore/1, sleep/1, breathe/1.
:- chr_constraint eat/1, live/1, rest/1, collect/2, pull/2.

snore(X) ==> breathe(X).
snore(X) ==> sleep(X).
sleep(X) ==> rest(X).

breathe(X) ==> live(X).
eat(X)     ==> live(X).
sleep(X)   ==> live(X).

live(X) \ live(X) <=> true.  % eliminates duplicates

collect(Who,L),snore(Who)   <=> collect(Who,[snore|L]).
collect(Who,L),sleep(Who)   <=> collect(Who,[sleep|L]).
collect(Who,L),breathe(Who) <=> collect(Who,[breathe|L]).
collect(Who,L),eat(Who)     <=> collect(Who,[eat|L]).
collect(Who,L),live(Who)    <=> collect(Who,[live|L]).
collect(Who,L),rest(Who)    <=> collect(Who,[rest|L]).

pull(Who,L) \ collect(Who2,L2) <=> Who = Who2, L = L2.
```

Now we just need to start SWI-Prolog, and issue these commands:

```
?- [sleep].
true.

?- sleep(lucy),
   collect(lucy,[]),
   pull(Who,L).
Who = lucy,
L = [rest,live,sleep],
pull(lucy,[rest,live,sleep]).


?- snore(john),
   collect(john,[]),
   pull(Who,L).
Who = john,
L = [rest,live,breathe,sleep,snore],
pull(john,[rest,live,breathe,sleep,snore]).
```

Comment: Hold on ... how do I get the results into a Prolog variable?

Comment: Ok, found how to do it. I had the same question a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You asked in a comment to Carlo's answer:

> Is there a way to expose the eat predicate and the like? It looks like
> I'm going to have a lot of unmatched predicate networks like owl and
> proton because I'm going to use few facts and a lot of semantic
> relations from Wordnet.

The issue here seems to be one of *closed-world assumption* (CWA) where predicates are *declared* (and thus can be called without generating errors) but not necessarily *defined*. In this case, as per CWA, what we cannot prove is true, is assumed to be false. E.g. the `eat/1` predicate in your example or the "lot of unmatched predicate networks" in your comment.

A possible solution would be to define your entities as Logtalk objects that implement a protocol (or a set of protocols) that declare all the predicates you want to use. Reusing your example:

```
:- protocol(predicates).

    :- public([
        breathe/0, sleep/0, rest/0, live/0,
        snore/0, eat/0
    ]).

:- end_protocol.


:- category(generic,
    implements(predicates)).

    breathe :- ::snore.
    sleep :- ::snore.
    rest :- ::sleep.
    live :- ::breathe; ::eat; ::sleep.

:- end_category.


:- object(john, imports(generic)).

    snore.

:- end_object.


:- object(lucy, imports(generic)).

    sleep.

:- end_object.
```

If we ask an entity (object) about a predicate that it doesn't define, the query will simply fail. For example (using SWI-Prolog as backend here but you can use most Prolog systems; assuming the code above is saved in a `code.lgt` file):

```
$ swilgt
...
?- {code}.
...

?- lucy::eat.
false.
```

If we want to find all objects that satisfy e.g. the `sleep/0` predicate:

```
?- findall(Object,
       (current_object(Object),
        conforms_to_protocol(Object, predicates),
        Object::sleep),
   Objects).
Objects = [john, lucy].
```

If we want to query all predicates satisfied by the objects (here with the simplifying assumption that all those predicates have zero arity):

```
?- setof(
       Name,
       Arity^(current_object(Object),
              conforms_to_protocol(Object, predicates),
              Object::current_predicate(Name/Arity),
              Object::Name),
       Predicates
   ).
Object = john,
Predicates = [breathe, live, rest, sleep, snore] ;
Object = lucy,
Predicates = [live, rest, sleep].
```

But, at least for the most common queries, handy predicate definitions would preferably be added to the `generic` category.

P.S. For more on the closed-world assumption and predicate semantics and also why Prolog modules fail to provide a sensible alternative solution see e.g. https://logtalk.org/2019/09/30/predicate-semantics.html